# Update a form value, after an update query sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi my problem is the after updating the db with a query, the value in the form won't change, even if the same value (ex. `team1`), at the bottom of the code is giving me the update value. To update the value in the form i've to refresh the page.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form-partite">
    Team Home: <input type="text" name="team1" value="<?php echo $team1 ?>">
    Team Away: <input type="text" name="team2" value="<?php echo $team2 ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['team1'] == "" || $_POST['team2'] == ""){
            echo "Devi inserire entrambe le squadre";
        } else {
            $team1 = $_POST['team1'];
            $team2 = $_POST['team2'];
            $data = array(
                'team1' => $team1,
                'team2' => $team2
            );
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb -> update( wp_partite, $data, array( id => '1' ) );
            global $wpdb;
            $partita = $wpdb -> get_row("SELECT team1, team2 FROM wp_partite");
            $team1 = $partita -> team1;
            $team2 = $partita -> team2;
            echo "Partita inserita: " . $team1 . " vs " . $team2 . "!";
            unset($_POST);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Luis, always call PHP before using its varaibles.
Also don't unset $_POST as it's a global variable and cannot be unsetted.
Unsetting global variables is a bad practice. Avoid it.

Also, define $team1 and $team2 before checking $_POST['submit'] so that they are always available and do not give undefined variable error.

Use trim so as you do not want user to fill spaces in your form.

You can unset team1 and team2 offsets inside $_POST though.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php 

    $team1 = $team2 = ''; // ADD THIS LINE, else form will show undefined variable error.

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (trim($_POST['team1']) == "" || trim($_POST['team2']) == ""){  // Modified
            echo "Devi inserire entrambe le squadre";
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'team1' => $_POST['team1'], // Modified
                'team2' => $_POST['team2'] // Modified
            );
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb -> update( wp_partite, $data, array( id => '1' ) );
            global $wpdb;
            $partita = $wpdb -> get_row("SELECT team1, team2 FROM wp_partite");
            $team1 = $partita -> team1;
            $team2 = $partita -> team2;
            echo "Partita inserita: " . $team1 . " vs " . $team2 . "!";
            unset($_POST['team1']); // Modified
            unset($_POST['team2']); // Modified
        }
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="form-partite">
    Team Home: <input type="text" name="team1" value="<?php echo $team1 ?>">
    Team Away: <input type="text" name="team2" value="<?php echo $team2 ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanx for the helpful explanation!

Comment: Your welcome.! Please accept an answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing the form before PHP, do it after PHP:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['team1'] == "" || $_POST['team2'] == ""){
            echo "Devi inserire entrambe le squadre";
        } else {
            $team1 = $_POST['team1'];
            $team2 = $_POST['team2'];
            $data = array(
                'team1' => $team1,
                'team2' => $team2
            );
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb -> update( wp_partite, $data, array( id => '1' ) );
            global $wpdb;
            $partita = $wpdb -> get_row("SELECT team1, team2 FROM wp_partite");
            $team1 = $partita -> team1;
            $team2 = $partita -> team2;
            echo "Partita inserita: " . $team1 . " vs " . $team2 . "!";
            unset($_POST);
        }
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post" id="form-partite">
    Team Home: <input type="text" name="team1" value="<?php echo $team1 ?>">
    Team Away: <input type="text" name="team2" value="<?php echo $team2 ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please set the question as answered @stefanotombari